# How to get a list of UDFs in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there an easy way to get the list of all UDFs that are available in Redshift?
Moreover, I would like to find UDFs with parameter types and search for UDFs by name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can query the `pg_proc` table to get all the UDFs available.

#### Filter by name

You can filter by name using the `proname` column:

`SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proname ILIKE '%<name_here>%';`

#### Filter by parameter type

You can filter by parameter types using the `proargtypes` column:

`SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proargtypes = 1043;`

Here, `1043` is `varchar` as can be seen by querying the `pg_type` table:

`SELECT * FROM pg_type WHERE typname ILIKE '%char%';`

#### Filter by parameter name

You can also filter by parameter name using the `proargnames` column:

`SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proargnames = ARRAY['foo'];`

***References:***

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/catalog-pg-proc.html

Comment: This was really useful.  Oddly enough, my sql client (Postico) required me to explicitly select the oids in order to see them like so: `select oid, * from pg_type;`.  Not really sure why, but it confused me for a good while.