# redshift alter udf change owner

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, alter

In order to drop a user in redshift, I have to change all privileges and ownership of this user.

The user however also owns user defined function in redshift.

How to change the owner of this user-defined-function?

```
[ ALTER FUNCTION f_.. OWNER TO xyz ]
```

didnt not work..

How do I check where this function is used?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, R.Zieglt's solution did NOT work for me. I needed to specify input parameters **types**, not names.

Here is my sample:

```
ALTER FUNCTION udf_name (text) OWNER TO admin;
```

#### Note

If you are not sure of the parameter types you can query the `pg_proc` table, filtering by `proname`:

```
SELECT proargtypes FROM pg_proc WHERE proname ILIKE udf_name;
```

You can then map a numeric type to its name using the `pg_type` table and filtering by `typname`:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_type WHERE typelem = 23;
```

(Taken from [Get a list of UDFs in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083500/how-to-get-a-list-of-udfs-in-redshift).)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually pretty simple, the input variables for the function have to be added:

`Alter Function function_name ( input1,input2,...) OWNER TO new_user`